# Swing component and jdk version issue

Tags: swing, combobox, java

I have a combo box. After selecting an item in combo box new JDialog opens.

1. When i use JDK 1.6_06, I am able
   to click on buttons in JDialog
   properly.
2. When i use JDK 1.6_24,
   then i need to click anywhere in
   JDialog first. Then only clicking on
   button works. Firstly i thought this
   is some issue with the focus. But
   component works fine with JDK
   1.6_06. But its a issue only with JDK 1.6_24.

I tried to google it. But didnt find any answer. Does anybody have any idea?

Comment: Are you using both JDKs on the same system? (Which one?) This looks like a Window manager issue.

Comment: (took the opportunity to upgrade from u23 to u24 :-) - but can't reproduce. How about a small runnable example which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Any chance of posting a SSCCE? http://sscce.org/

Comment: @Paulo: Yes, its a same machine
@kleopatra , unhillbilly: I tried with small swing application. I am not able to reproduce it.
But i found that the issue is with the threading. I have put my understaning in the third answer in this thread. Please let me know if I am correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@All: Aplogize for late reply. I was trying out different scenarios. And i have found that issue is with the threading. It seems that combo box is not yet finished its work, and jdialog is opened. And after that combo box tries to finish its work, so the focus is lost to the parent window. I tried opening dialog in thread:

```
             new Thread() {
                    public void run() {
                        // open dialog here
                    }
                }.start();
```

And it works fine. Now i am planning to open dialog using SwingWorker:

```
                 SwingWorker worker = new SwingWorker() {
                @Override
                protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    // open dialog here
                    return null;
                }
                 };
```

This is also working. Hope this is the right way. Please let me know, if I am doing a right thing.

Comment: SwingWorker is not used for this purpose. Can you post how you are opening the dialog? Is it being opened in a listener on the combo box?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the java versions - but putting dialog.setVisible(true) in SwingUtilities#invokeLater solved this issue some time back for me. YMMV.

Comment: The use of show() is deprecated, better use `setVisible(true)`